# Render form within html table

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to render an html form within a table. The problem is I load the page with AJAX and after that the button stops working (due to the tr and td placement).

Is there any way to manage this with html, javascript, php, or css?

This is what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image]

```
    echo "<tr id=\"$I_ID\" class=\"toggleEdit\">";
        echo "<form class=\"editRow\" name=\"editRow\" action=\"\" method=\"POST\">";
        echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"edit\">";
        echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"$thatTable\">";
        echo "<input type=\"hidden\" value=\"$I_ID\" name=\"I_ID\">";
        echo "<input type=\"hidden\" value=\"$row[1]\" name=\"$columns[1]\">";
        echo "<td>$row[1]</td>";
        for ($pointer = 2 ; $pointer < $countRows ; ++$pointer) {
            echo "<td><input type=\"text\" value=\"$row[$pointer]\" name=\"$columns[$pointer]\"></td>";
        }
        echo "<td><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submitEdit\" value=\"submit edit\"></td>";
    echo "</form>";
    echo "</tr>";
```

And this is what works:

[image]

```
    echo "<tr id=\"$I_ID\" class=\"toggleEdit\">";
        echo "<td id=\"tdEditRow\">";
        echo "<form class=\"editRow\" name=\"editRow\" action=\"\" method=\"POST\">";
        echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"edit\">";
        echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"$thatTable\">";
        echo "<input type=\"hidden\" value=\"$I_ID\" name=\"I_ID\">";
        echo "<input type=\"hidden\" value=\"$row[1]\" name=\"$columns[1]\">";
        echo "$row[1]";
        for ($pointer = 2 ; $pointer < $countRows ; ++$pointer) {
            echo "<input type=\"text\" value=\"$row[$pointer]\" name=\"$columns[$pointer]\">";
        }
        echo "<input type=\"submit\" id=\"submitEdit\" value=\"submit edit\">";
    echo "</form>";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: Could you explain the use of AJAX in this case ? I don't get why you don't just put in shape your form via html ? Is something prevent you from doing this ?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: I use AJAX to submit the select table data and render the results with .html.

Comment: Here the code: /* AJAX for table selection */
 $(document).on('change', '#values', function() {
     var switchTable = $(this).serialize();
 $.ajax({
  type: 'POST', 
  url: "IRCdrawTables.php",
  data: switchTable,
  cache: false,
  success: function(result){
   $('body').html(result);
  } //end result
 }); // end ajax 
 return false;
    }); // .change

Comment: Hello??? Is there anything further you'd like me to explain?